# Bing Spell Check API doesn't work

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

The Bing Spell Check API always returns me no suggestions even if there a mistakes in the input text, for example:

[image]

Comment: I think there is an undocumented minimum text length. If I do `helo+world` I get results

Comment: I just tested helo+world, same results: https://imgur.com/a/b4tqb https://imgur.com/a/mQLCB

Comment: Odd, I do get results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ble8w.png

Comment: What happens if you have a market query parameter, such as `mkt=en-US`?

Answer (score 1):

mode=Proof&mkt=en-us parameters yield better results, if you are not trying already. Also, for direct (curl) kind of requests put %2C for space rather than +. It works for me when I do "helo%2Cwrld" with the above parameters.